# Datepicker is not selecting corretly the previous values when we have two components on sencha ext js 7.2

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs7

I am having some issues with the date picker component on ext js 7.2.

Here is the fiddle to reproduce the behavior:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36h9

Basically, I have two date picker component on the same page, when I intercalated between this two-component I am getting the wrong selecting.

Steps:
1. Click on the first date picker icon.
2. Click on the second date picker icon.
3. Click on the first date picker icon again.
- Verify the wrong value selected on the component.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this bug appeared in versions > 7.0
Try to use the following override to fix it:

```
Ext.define('Override.picker.Picker', {
    override: 'Ext.picker.Picker',

    afterShow: function(me) {   
        me.callParent([me]);    
        me.scrollSlotsIntoView();   
        Ext.util.InputBlocker.blockInputs();    
    }
});
```

The fiddle with fix: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36lo

Comment: Hello Arthur, thanks so much. This override fixed the issue, We added on our project and it worked fine! Have a good day!